# Many layouts in Scroll View in android

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-scrollview

I want to have 3 layouts in my ScrollView but when I add them it actually doesn't scroll. I tried to put all layouts in different files, then include them, tried to put them in ListView and it doesn't work too. In this option, when I put in ScrollView the LinearLayout and there include the rest of the layouts the application show nothing. That's probably becouse I don't know how to refer to that nested layouts... This is my XML:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
    <ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:orientation="vertical"
        >
            <include layout="@layout/first"/>
            <include layout="@layout/second"/>
            <include layout="@layout/third"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**@EDIT** views included (all are the same so I put just one):

```
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/first"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And in the **main activity** I put the objects into layouts like this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
RelativeLayout first = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.first);
RelativeLayout second = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.second);
RelativeLayout third = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.third);

...some code creating views...

first.addView(myView1);
second.addView(myView2);
third.addView(myView3);
```

Comment: Have you set android:layout_height="wrap_content" in your Relativelayouts ?

Comment: Could you please post the 3 RelativeLayouts you are including?

Comment: Yeah, gonna update question

Comment: from what I can tell by the code you have posted so far: the problem seems to be in the views you create inside the '...some code creating views...' part.

Comment: @Bmuig you were right, I passed wrong layouts params to the view, thanks a lot, problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

Need to put fix size in included layout, for example:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/first"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
```

/>

I don`t understand why do you need to add view manually when you already added it to the layout.

You should also eliminate top `Linear Layout` since there is no use of it.